# phpbb and filesystem storage

Tags: image, file, filesystems, storage, phpbb

Can I save the images file on filesystem (no db) in phpbb?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually Avatars are stored in "/images/avatars/upload" directory. Standard images attached to messages are stored in "/files" directory in a hashed format. Any thumbnails you generate are stored as "thumbs_[hashed-code]" in that same "/files" directory.

Pete

Answer (score 0):

Images (uploaded avatars and attachements) *are* stored on the filesystem by phpBB, more specifically within the `store` directory.